# Getting Javascript stack trace on uncaught error on iPad Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, google-chrome, safari

I want to get stack traces from uncaught javascript errors.

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber, col, error) {
  // error.stack has the stacktrace, but not on iPad Chrome / Safari 
}
```

This works on Desktop Chrome (which uses the Blink rendering engine) but not on iPad Chrome/Safari.

I've also tried another method mentioned on https://bugsnag.com/blog/js-stacktraces/
which was to wrap the window.EventTarget.addEventListener like this:

```
var addEventListener = window.EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
window.EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function (event, callback, bubble) {
    addEventListener.call(this, event, wrap(callback), bubble);
}
```

But EventTarget doesn't exist either on the browsers in question either.

Is there any good way to get the javascript stack trace on these browsers?